# Keras ImageDataGenerator messing up with grey images, how to correctly augment greyscale image?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am analysing 16bit grey scale images.
After uploading greyscale image, everything looks fine.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
img = plt.imread('example_image.tif')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

## Or one can also do

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('example_image.tif', -cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
img1 = np.expand_dims(img, axis=2)
img2 = np.reshape(img1,[1,696,520,1])
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

When I checked my augmented images, they looks distorted. What am I doing wrong?

```
img1 = np.expand_dims(img, axis=2)
img2 = np.reshape(img1,[1,696,520,1])
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 4095,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

i=0
for batch in datagen.flow(img2, batch_size=1,
                          save_to_dir='C:/image_analysis', save_prefix='grey_check_', save_format='tif'):
    i += 1
    if i > 20:
        break
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

replace this line:

```
img2 = np.reshape(img1,[1,696,520,1])
```

on this:

```
img2 = np.reshape(img1,[1,520,696,1])
```